# Warum Rohr-Rohzucker und nicht Roh-Rohrzucker?

Tags: compound

Wann immer ich im Biosupermarkt vor dem Regal mit den Backzutaten stehe, zuckt mein innerer Zwangsneurotiker zusammen: Warum heißt es *Rohr-Rohzucker* und nicht *Roh-Rohrzucker*?

Intuitiv sagt mir mein Sprachverständnis, dass es sinnvoller und einfacher wäre, von

> rohem Rohrzucker  => *Roh-Rohrzucker*

zu sprechen, als von

> Rohzucker, welcher aus Zuckerrohr gefertigt ist => *Rohr-Rohzucker*

Mal ganz abgesehen davon, dass es ein wunderbarer Zungenbrecher für Nicht-Muttersprachige ist: Gibt es dazu irgendeine grammatikalisch sinnvolle Erklärung, oder ist das einfach eine Konvention der Zuckerindustrie?

[Update:]
Offenbar gibt es tatsächlich beide Schreibweisen im Handel. Matthias' Antwort (ebenso wie Huberts Kommentar) zeigt jedoch auf, warum die zweite Variante grammatikalisch sinnvoller ist, da sie nicht versehentlich *"Rohr-Ohrzucker"* gelesen werden kann, wenn man den Bindestrich weglässt.

Comment: Bist du sicher, dass das so verbreitet ist? Sehe und finde stets nur „Roh-Rohrzucker“, sei es im Welt-/Bioladen oder im Web.

Comment: Wird der Rohr-Rohzucker in dieser Verpackung auch in der Schweiz vertrieben?

Comment: @chirlu Schweizer Anbieter denken offenbar auch in beide Richtungen: Migros (lt. Website) bietet "Rohzucker aus Zuckerrohr" und "Rohrzucker", der auf den Bildern sehr "roh" aussieht. Coop hat "Rohrohrzuckersticks"...

Comment: In welcher Verpackung - in Rohren? ;)

Comment: Ohne Bindestrich wird's ja noch kurioser. Ist der Rohrohrzucker ein Roh-Rohrzucker, oder vielleicht doch ein Rohr-Ohrzucker? - Der Hund von Klaus kann nämlich auf zwei unterschiedliche Weisen mit seinen Ohren zucken. Es ist sehr interessant, diese verschiedenen Ohrzucker zu beobachten. Klaus verwendet manchmal einen Trinkhalm, also ein Rohr, mit dem er das Ohr des Hundes berührt. Dabei zuckt das Ohr anders, als wenn er auf das Ohr pustet. Erst gestern führe er diesen Trick wieder vor, und jedermann konnte es sehen: Der Pusteohrzucker war deutlich anders als der Rohrohrzucker.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast detailiert und schlüssig wie immer ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich möchte noch einen anderen Aspekt ins Spiel bringen. Der bei uns daheim bevorzugte Anbieter schreibt

> MARKE
>   Rohrohr
>   Zucker

auf seine Tüten. Das bringt mich abwechselnd zum Weinen und Lachen. Ersteres wegen des Deppenleerzeichens (es fehlt der Bindestrich nach "Rohrohr"), und letzteres, weil ich auf den ersten Blick erst einmal "Rohr-Ohr" lese (auch nach jahrelanger Gewöhnung an den Anblick).

Diese Verwechslungsgefahr besteht bei Rohrrohzucker nicht, und wer die Wahl hat, weil ja beide Varianten möglich sind, mag sich vielleicht aus diesem Grund für letzteres entscheiden.

Comment: Zum Rohr-Ohr habe ich bei der Frage einen Kommentar geschrieben. Leider habe ich deine Antwort erst danach gelesen, sonst hätte ich diesen Kommentar hier hinterlassen.

Comment: Von Verwechslungsgefahr würde ich nicht sprechen. Was soll denn ein Rohr-Ohr sein?

Answer (score 11):

Von einer Konvention würde ich keinesfalls sprechen, zumal die Bezeichnungen offenbar wild durcheinander gehen:

Du schreibst von **Rohr-Rohzucker**, z.B. von Südzucker,
@dakab kauft **Roh-Rohrzucker**, z.B. von Naturata
und in meinem Vorratsschrank steht **Rohrohrzucker** (ohne Bindestrich) von Sessler.

Ansonsten bleibt es dem Hersteller und seinem Produkt- bzw. Sprachverständnis überlassen, ob er "unraffinierten Rohrzucker" oder "Rohzucker aus Zuckerrohr" anbietet - und die Reihenfolge im zusammengesetzten Substantiv entsprechend bildet. Für den Koch oder Teetrinker ist der Unterschied irrelevant<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 Wobei ich zugeben muss, dass ich zumindest eine Person kenne, die daran scheitern würde, wenn ich ihr auf den Einkaufszettel die eine Bezeichnung schreiben würde, der Laden dagegen das Produkt unter der anderen anbietet...</sup>

Comment: ＋１ für Naturata-Volltreffer (und Argumentation vermischter, konventionsloser Schreibweisen).

Comment: Schreib mich als zweite Person auf diese Liste … aber warum überhaupt derart detaillierte Angaben auf der Einkaufsliste machen; Rohzucker tuts doch vollkommen … ^^'

Answer (score 4):

Die Reihenfolge der Auflistung spiegelt wider, was dem Schreiber die wichtigere Eigenschaft ist, nämlich diejenige, die näher am Grundwort steht. Demnach wäre bei Zucker die Rohheit wichtiger als Herkunftspflanze, was mir wegen der geringeren Haltbarkeit und der geschmacklichen Kompromisse plausibel erscheint. Man kann das leicht an anderen Beispielen wie Kinder-Sonnenbrille oder Sonnen-Kinderbrille durchspielen.